# ubuntu bash scripting: configure file missing?

Tags: bash, scripting, ubuntu

in "Bash Guide for Beginners", it's said:

Bash is the GNU shell, compatible with the Bourne shell and incorporating many useful features from other shells. When the shell is started, it reads its configuration files. The most important are:

```
/etc/profile

~/.bash_profile

~/.bashrc
```

however, in my ubuntu 11.10,
 - there's no "~/.bash_profile": file explorer does not show it, and "ls -l ~/.bash_profile" says "No Such file or directory"
 - there are "/etc/profile" and "~/.bashrc", but they don't show up in file explorer, only "ls -l /etc/profile" and "ls -l /.bashrc" shows the result.

is there something missing during my installation?

Comment: The reason `ls` doesn't show `.bashrc` is that the default is to not show dot files. Try `ls -a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's fine if those files aren't there, they'll just be ignored. To get a complete list of what's loaded and in what order, run `man bash` and check the section on INVOCATION (use "/" and type in INVOCATION to search)

Edit: saving @athos a man bash call ;)

> When  bash  is  invoked  as  an  interactive  login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file
>          /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes com‐
>          mands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.
>
> When  an  interactive  shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if these files exist.  This
>          may be inhibited by using the --norc option.  The --rcfile file option will force bash to read and execute  commands  from  file  instead  of  /etc/bash.bashrc  and
>          ~/.bashrc.

Comment: thanks, i'll read the book through first, currently i have no idea of "INVOCATION" yet :p

Comment: Oh come on, Invocation refers to what happens when you start bash. It's just a section in the manual. Besides, it's good that you have a look at the *raw* documentation for reference ;)

Comment: i'll do that.. only installed ubuntu yesterday.. so please bear with my primary school questions :)

Comment: I added the bit of the manual I was referring to in the answer. Have fun and come back with more questions!

Answer (score 1):

Here I discuss, how to set JAVA_HOME variable and the PATH variable to your Java installation.

First using the terminal open the .bashrc which is at your home.

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Now add the following to the end of the file.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

NOTE: If /usr/lib/jvm/java does not match the actual JAVA_HOME path in your environment, then set the actual JAVA_HOME, where you have installed Java in your machine.

Now run,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then, try running the following commands and check whether your getting the appropriate responses:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java
echo $PATH
:/usr/lib/jvm/java/bin
```

If it not work try after restarting

Answer (score 0):

It also reads `/etc/bashrc`, which is probably present on your system.
I'm pretty sure that you also have `~/.profile` (that one it reads as well) or `~/.bashrc`.

If those files are missing, feel free to create them and fill with whatever you need.

Comment: no... "ls -l /etc/bashrc" also says "No such file or directory".

Comment: If you create a `.bash_profile` it will take precedence over your regular `.profile` - this might be confusing. Just saying "feel free" has a caveat. The common pattern is to just use `.profile`, which will be read by other Bourne-compatible shells; or, if you need a `. bash_profile`, to have it source the regular `.profile` from within it (and also source `.bashrc` IIRC).

Comment: It's not really precedence. They will all be read, .bash_profile first, then .bash_login and then .profile, in that order. So if you put contradictory statements there - well.. ;) I normally just create one and link the others to it for compatibility.